# Referencing UIBarButtonItem in it's Selector Action Function

Tags: ios, uibutton, action, selector, uiswitch

I'm implementing a pretty standard select button for a UINavigationItem (rightBarButtonItem). The way I'm going about it is instantiating it in the viewDidLoad function. I'm passing a selector as an action, then writing that selector function outside of the viewDidLoad function.

Obvious problem is, the navigation selection button is no longer in scope of the selector function, so I can't reference and work with it.

There must be many ways to implement the Select navigation button. I want it to act like a switch in a collection view, so I can select and highlight collection view cells only when the select button has been hit. For this, my selector action will turn the myButton.selected Boolean value on and off, like a switch (so I don't think I need a UISwitch here).

Enough explanation, here is the code;

```
class GalleryViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
....

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...

    //MARK: Select button
    let mySelector: Selector = #selector(GalleryViewController.selectSelector)
    let selectButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Select", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: mySelector)

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = selectButton

}

//MARK: Select Button Function
func selectSelector() {
    //Toggle selectButton ON/OFF here, and more

}
```

If you have a nifty way of creating a navigationBar barButtonItem to toggle the state of collectionViewCells, I'd love to hear it! Just provide a complete answer, don't assume I know much at all (still feel like I faceroll in Xcode)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options; You could store a reference to the `UIBarButtonItem` in a property rather than a local variable, so that you can use it in your action handler function or you could get the reference from `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`, but the simplest way is just to take advantage of the fact that the `UIBarButtonItem` will be passed to your action handler function:

```
func selectSelector(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    //Toggle selectButton ON/OFF here, and more
}
```